# tcl Making single list from sublist

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

Converting List of list into single list. for example:

List1 {1 2 {3 4 5} 6 7 {8} 9 10 {{11 12} 13} 14 {15} 16 {{{{17} 18} 19} 20} 21 22 {23} 24 25}
convert to
List1 { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25}

How to convert it??

Comment: This is an easy task using a recursive function. What do you have up to now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the leaves are simple words (e.g., letters, numbers, periods, but *absolutely no* Tcl metacharacters) it's fairly simple with `join`:

```
set s {1 2 {3 4 5} 6 7 {8} 9 10 {{11 12} 13} 14 {15} 16 {{{{17} 18} 19} 20} 21 22 {23} 24 25}
while {[set t [join $s]] ne $s} {set s $t}
puts $s
# => 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

To see how this works, try putting a `puts` inside the loop, as in this interactive session:

```
% while {[set t [join $s]] ne $s} {
    puts $t
    set s $t
}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 {11 12} 13 14 15 16 {{{17} 18} 19} 20 21 22 23 24 25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 {{17} 18} 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 {17} 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Note that this will not work if you produce an invalid list at any point during the expansion, hence why it is important to avoid metacharacters (especially `\`, `{` and `}`). It's also not usual to do this sort of thing in production code; needing it is usually an indication of something elsewhere having gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With tcllib:

```
package require struct::list
set List1 {1 2 {3 4 5} 6 7 {8} 9 10 {{11 12} 13} 14 {15} 16 {{{{17} 18} 19} 20} 21 22 {23} 24 25}
puts [struct::list flatten -full $List1]
```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

[Documentation](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_list.html)